# How to mark a testthat test as an expected failure?

Tags: r, testthat

In python there's a nice workflow where you can write a test as an expected failure (e.g. `pytest.mark.xfail`) and run tests with mere warnings when they fail. This makes for a great test-driven-development workflow, where you can commit failing tests before writing the code that fixes them. However the best that I've been able to do in R is to comment out failing tests.

What is the recommended way to write such xfailing tests in the R `testthat` library?

Comment: `expect_error` & `expect_failure`. The "recommended" way [is given by the author of `testthat`](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Wickham.pdf)

Comment: @SymbolixAU, Thanks, `expect_failure` is simpler than I anticipated!

Comment: @SymbolixAU Actually, `expect_failure` is for marking expectations, not tests. What I am looking for is something to wrap a test as a known failure, so that it can be marked fixed in a later PR.